# How to stop receiving group text messages

Tags: sms

How do I stop receiving text replies from people in a "group conversation"? For example, if user A sends a group text message, to users B, C and D, and myself (user E), I just want to see user A's original text message and not replies from users B, C, and D. Is there any way to accomplish this on any Android OS? I dont mean iMessage (that is [discussed here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32142/is-there-a-way-to-unsubscribe-from-group-texts-in-ios-5), and the answer there seems to be 'no').

If not, can somebody explain why this limitation exists and if the carriers/phone manufacturers have indicated any awareness of this as a problem (or any future plans to change this 'feature')?